# How to configure Fortigate 60D as L2PT/IPSEC client

Tags: vpn, ipsec, l2tp, fortigate

I have a firewall Fortigate 60D and I need to create a tunnel to a L2TP/IPSEC server, so the firewall has to act as a client.

Is it possible?

I configured the L2TP/IPSEC server on a Linux Debian machine using Libreswan and I can connect to it using an android phone but I am not able to do the same with the Fortigate firewall.

This is my server ipsec.conf:

```
version 2.0

config setup
  dumpdir=/var/run/pluto/
  nat_traversal=yes
  virtual_private=%v4:10.0.0.0/8,%v4:192.168.0.0/16,%v4:172.16.0.0/12,%v4:!10.10.6.0/24
  oe=off
  protostack=netkey
  nhelpers=0
  interfaces=%defaultroute

conn vpnpsk
  connaddrfamily=ipv4
  auto=add
  left=public_server_ip
  leftid=public_server_ip
  leftsubnet=public_server_ip/32
  leftnexthop=%defaultroute
  leftprotoport=17/1701
  rightprotoport=17/%any
  right=%any
  rightsubnetwithin=0.0.0.0/0
  forceencaps=yes
  authby=secret
  pfs=no
  type=transport
  auth=esp
  ike=3des-sha1,aes-sha1
  phase2alg=3des-sha1,aes-sha1
  rekey=no
  keyingtries=5
  dpddelay=30
  dpdtimeout=120
  dpdaction=clear
```

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the connection type in the GUI under "Remote Gateway".  Setting it to "Dialup User" is what you want.

[image: VPN Edit]

You can also use the "type" option in the phase1-interface table.

```
conf vpn ipsec phase1-interface
    edit <tunnel>
        set type dynamic ?

        static     Remote VPN gateway has fixed IP address.
        dynamic    Remote VPN gateway has dynamic IP address.
        ddns       Remote VPN gateway has dynamic IP address and is a dynamic DNS client.

        set type dynamic

    end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the wizard or CLI on the Fortigate - configure it on the Fortigate side as a dialup VPN instead of site-to-site.